# convert ' June 09 2021, 01:50:00 PM' to 2021-06-09 13:50:00 dateformat in NODEJS

Tags: node.js, date, timestamp, datetime-format

How to convert this ' June 09 2021, 01:50:00 PM' to 2021-06-09 13:50:00   dateformat  in NODEJS.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert like this:

```
 const convertDateTo24Hour = (date) => {
 var elem = date.split(',');
var msplit = date.split(' ');

  let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
 "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
 let index = months.indexOf(msplit[0]) + 1;
 let newDate = msplit[2].replace(',','') + "-" + index + "-" + msplit[1];

  var stSplit = elem[1].split(' ');
 var abc = stSplit[1].split(":");
 var stHour = abc[0];
 var stMin = abc[1];
 var stSec = abc[2];
 var stAmPm = elem[1].split(" ");

 if (stAmPm[2] == 'PM') {
   if (stHour != 12) {
   stHour = stHour * 1 + 12;
 }
 } else if (stAmPm[2] == 'AM' && stHour == '12') {
   stHour = stHour - 12;
 } else {
 stHour = stHour;
 }

return newDate + " " + stHour + ':' + stMin + ":" + stSec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date constructor to parse and then [Date.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to format to an ISO date output, like so:

```js
const input = 'June 09 2021, 01:50:00 PM';
const inputFormat = 'MMMM DD YYYY H:mm:ss a';

const d = new Date(input);
console.log('Result:', d.toLocaleString('sv'));
```

Comment: Moment.js can not use for now.